# Proving $Perm(S)\cong Perm(T)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am trying to prove this proposition:

### Let $f:S\to T$ be a bijection of sets. Then $Perm(S)\cong Perm(T)$.

I clearly want to show that $\phi: Perm(S) \to Perm (T)$ is an isomorphism with, $\sigma \mapsto f\circ \sigma \circ f^{-1}$. I am having trouble showing that $\phi%$ is a group homomorphism. The mapping is confusing me. For $\sigma, \tau \in Perm(S)$, I need to show that $\phi(\sigma \tau)=\phi(\sigma)\phi(\tau)$. So,

LHS=$\phi(\sigma \tau)=f\circ\sigma\tau\circ f^{-1}$=? This is where I am stuck. Given the RHS I could probably 'fudge' the proof to get to my desired result. This of course, is no fun though.

Thank you to all in advanced for your help!

Comment: Hint: $\sigma\tau=\sigma 1_S\tau$.

Comment: The computation is more natural if you start from the RHS to get the LHS.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the operations ... $\phi(\sigma)\phi(\tau)$ refers to which operation ("standard" multiplication, or composition?)

Comment: @user1. I see it :D ! Thank you !

Comment: @Pece. How do you define natural? But yes, that way works beautifully too ! Thank you to both !

Comment: $f\circ \sigma \circ \tau\circ f^{-1}=f\circ \sigma \circ f^{-1}\circ f\circ \tau\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: @eXtremiity _Natural_ was not a mathematical term here. I meant that it was more obvious from RHS to LHS than the other way around.